python requests Content-Disposition: form-data
I am looking into using cloudflare's KV and I see a nasty looking requests snippet here:https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/workers-kv-namespace-write-key-value-pair-with-metadata
To summarise I would like to send some payload but CF is showing me:
import requests

url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/account_id/storage/kv/namespaces/namespace_id/values/key_name"

payload = "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"value\"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--\r\n\r\n"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
    "Authorization": "Bearer undefined"
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

I would like to paramterise the metadata and value fields but I am struggling to see how I can do this in python efficiently without mistakes since the string looks nasty :(
ps: I am using the requests library and python 3.12.

Looking at the documentation you can try this snippet:
import json

import requests


def kv_put(key, value, metadata):
    api_token = "<API TOKEN>"
    account_id = "<ACCOUNT ID>"
    ns_id = "<NS ID>"

    url = (
        "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/%s/storage/kv/namespaces/%s/values/%s"
        % (account_id, ns_id, key)
    )

    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % api_token,
    }

    return requests.put(
        url, headers=headers, files=dict(metadata=json.dumps(metadata), value=value)
    ).json()


print(kv_put("my_key", "my_value", {"someMetadataKey": "someMetadataValue"}))

According https://httpbin.org/put the request looks like:
{
    "args": {},
    "data": "",
    "files": {
        "metadata": '{"someMetadataKey": "someMetadataValue"}',
        "value": "my_value",
    },
    "form": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Authorization": "Bearer <API TOKEN>",
        "Content-Length": "300",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=49368fcdb85df44d4dea137a5bd2ed8b",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.31.0",
    },
    "json": None,
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/put",
}

